# Adding animations to alertdialogs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-alertdialog

i want to display a list of alert dialogs with animations(left,right,fade in ,fade out) one by one like swiping the introduction screens using view pager how can i achieve this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can animate them through `windowAnimations` property:

```
yourDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
```

And by setting `animation transition`:

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you please provide a link for complete reference

Comment: Its almost all. You just have to apply `windowsAnimations` property to all your `AlerdDialogs` and on First Dialog dissmis, open Second Dialog and so on

Comment: yes, i have applied those with left and right animations but the problem i was getting is alert dialog is coming from right to left and whenever i want to display another dialog after performing an action it is going back towards right side and second one is coming from right side,but what i want is the first dialog should move towards left side and second dialog should come from right side..

Comment: Than you have to play with position of starting point in transitions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer.

We have to take four animation files under res->anim folder(if not present create it)

#### slide_in_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="2000" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="2000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

#### slide_in-right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="2000" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <alpha android:duration="2000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

#### slide_out_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="2000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="2000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

#### slide_out_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="2000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="2000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

then for testing purpose i have taken these two xml files

#### activity_price

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="How far you are willing to\n travel for food" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="$" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="$$" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:text="$$$"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="$$$$"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### activity_travel_qtn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="How far you are willing to \n\t\t\ttravel for food" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5 miles" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="10 miles" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="more" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:text="previous"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <Button
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:text="next"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

then these files corresponding activities

#### ActivityPrice

```
public class ActivityPrice extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button price1,price2,price3,price4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_price);

        price1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        price2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        price3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        price4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


        price1.setOnClickListener(this);
        price2.setOnClickListener(this);
        price3.setOnClickListener(this);
        price4.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityPrice.this, ActivityTravel.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent j = new Intent(ActivityPrice.this, ActivityTravel.class);
                startActivity(j);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                Intent k = new Intent(ActivityPrice.this, ActivityTravel.class);
                startActivity(k);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                Intent l = new Intent(ActivityPrice.this, ActivityTravel.class);
                startActivity(l);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### ActivityTravel

```
public class ActivityTravel extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Button travel1,travel2,travel3,previous,next;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel_qtn);

        travel1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        travel2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        travel3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        previous= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);


        previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
     switch (v.getId())
     {
         case R.id.button9:
             Intent i = new Intent(ActivityTravel.this, ActivityPrice.class);
             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             startActivity(i);
             overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_righ);
             break;
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve  using jQuery Ui Plugin .Refer below link :
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Comment: How is this Android?